# How change WSL ubuntu on Windows initial shell path?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have installed WSL(Windows subsystem for Linx) on my windows 10 pro. After WSL I installed ubuntu from windows store. After installation I started ubuntu from windows terminal.

My command line is like this:

```
ubuntu@DESKTOP-SP80BRM: /mnt/c/Users/mywinuser
```

But it should be like following:

```
ubuntu@DESKTOP-SP80BRM:
```

Because when I installed on virual machines "/mnt/c/Users/mywinuser" does not appear. How can I remove this path?

Comment: The path is equivalent / the same before and after running the `wsl` command inside the Windows Terminal Preview.  If you want to go to the Linux home directory do `cd ~` after running `wsl` or use `wsl ~` to start with.

Answer (score 0):

First, find where is your home on windows using network path:

run (win+r) \\wsl$

[find your home on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tVU0.png)

Now open your settings.json and change the property "startingDirectory"
to "//wsl$/Ubuntu/home/YOUR HOME"

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-general

Comment: \\wsl$  directory contains two folders "docker-desktop" and "docker-desktop-data"

Comment: \\wsl$ or \\wsl$\Ubuntu?

Comment: \\wsl$ contains. Ubuntu folder does not exist in.